# Does stopping X server in Ubuntu 16.04 KDE have any negative effect while logged in?

Tags: grub2, kde, xserver, sddm

I use Ubuntu mostly for file management on an older PC with KDE installed. I rarely need GUI, most things I do using SSH and Samba unless I am syncing files from my online accounts back and forth or something that can't be done or done easy enough on terminal.

I usually use

```
sudo service sddm stop
```

once I'm done to keep the memory usage down while letting transfers run in the background using samba and stuff.

Is using `sudo service sddm stop` while logged in a bad idea? I know I can disable GUI from boot problem is I always randomly need to use the GUI and it would be a pain to have to keep restarting and editing GRUB every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is OK to stop the X server.

---

An alternative, that will use less resources is to install a minimal system from the Ubuntu `mini.iso` or the Ubuntu server iso file, and after logging into the minimal installed system with only a text screen add a light-weight window manager (for example Fluxbox) and the few necessary GUI tools.

Then you can start the GUI with `startx` (it will not start automatically so that you must exit it every time).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install fluxbox xinit xterm openssh-server

sudo apt-get install your-particular-gui-tools
```

You can start the window manager with the following command

```
startx
```

and manage it via right-clicking to get menus (where you can also exit from the window manager and return to the text screen).

If you use

```
ssh -X user@network-address
```

you can use several (but not all) graphical applications remotely via `ssh`.

Comment: Thx I will look into that, I have switched to XFCE now, might try MATE